# WHat is the first long string optional argument for ssh and tcpdump that prints their version?

Tags: ssh, command-line, command, tcpdump

What is the first flag/option in the man pages of `ssh` and `tcpdump`?

```
ssh -1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy 

tcpdump  -AdDefIKlLnNOpqRStuUvxX
```

How is it called, why is it there, what conventions are there about it, what else uses it, why do most commands don't have it...

I couldn't find anything about it, so whatever you can tell me would be appreciated.

I do know however that it prints the version I am using and in the case of tcpdump, usage options as well.

I thought that it lists all possible flags, but it doesn't, `-c -C` are flags for `tcpdump` and not in that string for example, so is `-b` for `ssh`.

Answer (score 5):

My man page for `ssh` starts with:

```
ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]...
```

which is the same usage guide it prints if invoked e.g. with just `ssh`.

The first string there is just shorthand for the numerous single-character options which don't take arguments (it's shorter than writing `[-1] [-2] [-4]`...). The ones that take arguments are listed separately, probably to tell you what the argument is supposed to be.

Later on, the manual mentions that `-V` is actually the option to have 'ssh' print its version:

```
 -V      Display the version number and exit.
```